# get updated cell in datatable - primefaces - java

Tags: java, primefaces

In my datatable has several fields. My intention is that when you edit any of these fields and press the button , this row will be sent to my backbean to be changed.

The problem is that when the object is sent to the Backbean , it comes with the original properties (values).

I need the datatable to be updated when the field is edited and send this new value to my backbean.

Any sugestions? in add, im trying to avoid using primefaces in my backbean... ive made it so far..

My datatable

```
<h:form id="formBean">
<p:dataTable id="dataTableBean"
             var="modulo" 
             value="#{moduloBean.listModulo}"
             paginator="true"
             rows="15"
             resizableColumns="true">


    <p:column headerText="Id"><h:outputText value="#{modulo.id}"/></p:column>
    <p:column id="columnNmDescricao"
              headerText="Descrição">
        <p:inputText id="inputNmDescricao" value="#{modulo.nmDescricao}">
            <p:ajax event="change"
                    update=":formTabFuncionalidade:tabViewTabFuncionalidade:tabViewAcaoFuncionalidade:formBean:dataTableBean"
                    process="@this :formTabFuncionalidade:tabViewTabFuncionalidade:tabViewAcaoFuncionalidade:formBean:dataTableBean:0:inputNmDescricao"/>
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Ativo"><h:outputText value="#{modulo.ativo.nmAtivo}"/></p:column>

    <!-- Coluna para Ações. Trocar apenas os 2 últimos parâmetros do callSubAcaoMethod -->
    <p:column id="columnAcoes"
              headerText="Ações">
        <c:forEach items="#{funcionalidade.listAcao}"
                   var="subAcao">
            <c:if test="#{!subAcao.tipoAcao.flPrincipal}">
                <p:commandButton id="btnAcoes"
                                 value="#{subAcao.tipoAcao.nmDescricao}"
                                 icon="#{subAcao.tipoAcao.nmIcone}"
                                 action="#{segurancaBean.callSubAcaoMethod(subAcao, moduloBean.class, modulo)}"
                                 process="@this"/>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>  
</h:form>
```

my callSubAcaoMethod

```
    public void callSubAcaoMethod(Acao acao, Class bean, Object objeto){
    try {
        /* Método de instanciar um objeto dinamicamente em uso de CDI */
        Object objBean = CDI.current().select(bean).get();

        /* Estou chamando o método do Bean, dando como parâmetro suas ações e a classe que será alterada */
        Method method = bean.getMethod(acao.getTipoAcao().getNmBean(), objeto.getClass());
        method.invoke(objBean, objeto);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SegurancaBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The method i want to call

```
    public void btnAlterar(Modulo entity){
    System.out.println(entity);
    System.out.println(entity.getId());
    System.out.println(entity.getNmDescricao());
    System.out.println(entity.getAtivo().getNmAtivo()); 
}
```

Comment: why not just use the built it edit of primefaces datatable? shown here (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) You can see there that it edits the value in the backing bean

Comment: my intention is to get the updated object when i click in my command Button.. it will call a method in my backbean to update this value...

this commandButton is available by users permission and i really dont want to change it

Comment: Use inputText to show value, and on button process the whole table. Remove all  editMode="cell"  </p:cellEditor> stuff
                 editable="true"

Comment: i changed to inputText, removed all cellEditing stuff and add the process="dataTable"

didnt workout :/

Comment: can you try adding process="modelInput" as attribute in your commandButton

Comment: Use process="@this namingContainerID:dataTable" yo need to put real id od your dataTable, to find out what it is you can seach for dataTable in console or right click on table and inspect element, if you are using chrome. Something like id of your ":formID:dataTable"

Comment: didnt worked yet... i added a commantButton with the object in parameter but i still get the old value...
So i think the solution is to update the row before processing the button... any sugestions how to make it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{modulo.nmDescricao}" style="width:96%"/>
```

with

```
<p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{modulo.nmDescricao}" style="width:96%">
<p:ajax event="change" proces="@this :formID:dataTable:modelInput" update=":formID:dataTable"></p:ajax></p:inputText>
```

You need to update model's new value with ajax and update table with it, so when you send row object to back been it is with new vale.

With button you send row object to back-bean method btnAlterar like this.

```
<p:commandButton value="#{subAcao.tipoAcao.nmDescricao}"
   icon="#{subAcao.tipoAcao.nmIcone}"
   action="#{WhatEverBeanHasMe.btnAlterar(modulo)}"
   process="@this"
 />
```

Comment: Please improve your answer with some text explaining things…  noone learns from thisn

Comment: hi Dijana, thanks for the answer. Well, i just edited my tutorial xhtml code with these changes that u said.. i didnt worked yet.

i still dont understand why the datatable isnt updating.. the ajax is working correctly when i change the input value but when i call my action it stills prints me the old object

Comment: update=":formTabFuncionalidade:tabViewTabFuncionalidade:tabViewAcaoFuncionalidade:formBean:dataTableBean" -  formTabFuncionalidade,formBean are you form nesting? Do you have form inside a form? After procese is done you see changes in back bean listModulo? After update of dTable is new value shown or old one? You can check by breakpoint in getter and setter of listModulo to check when process or update is executing.

Comment: Hi Dijana, thanks again for feedback and sorry to be late in answer.. i got some personal issues..

Well, i did some tests
After button proccess i cant see any changes in bean
After update, the new value stays
if i set a listener in Ajax, it prints me the new value on console!

Comment: You didn't answer the form nesting part, your problem is somewhere else. To be 100% you are processing correct part, in inputText put class="forTesting" and in commandButton put process="@this @(.forTesting)"

Comment: nvm, got it working now !

I just added `process="@this dataTableBean"` in my commandButton